# Array to string conversion in D:\wamp\www\controle\exercice8.php using php

Tags: php

hi help me solve this exercise, and sorry because I am a beginner in php, here is the exercise:
give the code of a PHP function which takes as parameter an associative array `$tab_asso` as well as a numbered array `$keys` containing the keys of the elements of `$tab_asso` displays all the elements of `$ tab_asso`.

```
  <html>
    
   <head>
      <title>order</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
   
      <?php
         function afficheFunction(array $tab_asso,array $clefs) {
            $count = count($tab_asso);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
              echo "champ  : " . $tab_asso[$i] . "<br>";
             }
              return $tab_asso;
            }
         echo "voila la table " .afficheFunction(array(10,11,12,13),array());
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't echo an array. You must iterate it with something like a `foreach` and then echo individual elements.

Comment: @El_Vanja thx for u answer ,but if u can explain more plzzz

Comment: See the API: [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), they have example usage too.

Comment: Well, how are you expecting PHP to display `array(10,11,12,13)` on the screen? It has no idea what you want it to look like - because it's a data structure, not a piece of text. Therefore you must write a `foreach` loop and take each item from the array, and echo it in whatever format you actually want it to appear in.

Comment: By the way, your function / example doesn't solve the exercise because `array(10,11,12,13)` is not an **associative** array. Go and find out what one of those is, and then try again.

Comment: @ADyson I modified my question the array is displayed well, but the error remains

Comment: The error is still there because `echo "voila la table " .afficheFunction(array(10,11,12,13),array());` still tries to echo the array returned from the function directly. If you're going to echo within the function now, then you can just replace this line with `afficheFunction(array(10,11,12,13),array());` instead. Now you need to change it to use an associative array, and use the $clefs array as directed by your instructions (although admittedly, I don't understand that bit, maybe it's lost in your translation.)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments you cannot echo an array only strings.
The Massage means its not possible to covert Arrays to strings.
You can use for example var_dump(afficheFunction()).

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php